# Google signin users list

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Google auth for signing and i want to know how many users are registered in it. is there any console to see that list?

Facebook is giving user list who is using your app means who logged in your app. I want to know if Google is providing such info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase with Google sign in to track users of your app.
After you sign in with Google, get the Google ID token, initialize a Firebase AuthCredential with that and signInWithCredential. You will be able to list all the users using the app either through the Firebase User Console or programmatically via the Firebase Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

Comment: I want something like console ui on firebase site. Is there any page?

Comment: Not sure, I understand. Firebase already provides a Console with a UI that shows all your users (email/pass, facebook, google, phone, etc). You can use that for free to list all your users without having to build all that functionality on your own.

Comment: You are talking about firebase authentication. I am asking about gmail signed user list. not firebase auth user list.

Comment: Google sign in does not provide you with what you want. You can't see the list of users unless you track them and save them and build an interface to display them. Firebase Auth supports google sign-in and provides you with a way to lookup all your users for free. In this case, if you only want to support Google users, then you will only see Google users. It would be an additive feature.